# JavaScript Json row undefined for TreeView

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a question. When querying my Json object, although i have my Field as same name and all Json rows available give me an error that is **undefined**.

```
//e.g: row.DepParentId
```

Bellow is my code. Am I missing some tag?

```
function convert(rows) {
    debugger;
    function exists(rows, parent) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (rows[i].DepId === parent) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    var nodes = [];
    // get the top level nodes
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        if (!exists(rows, row.DepParentId)) {
            nodes.push({
                id: row.DepId,
                name: row.Title
            });
        }
    }
    var toDo = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        toDo.push(nodes[i]);
    }
    while (toDo.length) {
        var node = toDo.shift();
        // the parent node
        // get the children nodes
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows[i];
            if (row.DepParentId == node.Id) {
                var child = {
                    Id: row.DepId,
                    Name: row.Title
                };
                if (node.options) {
                    node.options.push(child);
                } else {
                    node.options = [child];
                }
                toDo.push(child);
            }
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

My Json example for one row picked from Firefox

```
    "{"DepId":7,"DepParentId":3,"Title":"OTT"}"
```

Thanks for helping
Joao

Comment: it might be better to also tell us why you are doing this? this looks like one of those problems that can be solved with 5 lines of underscore

Comment: I'm trying to populate a TreeView from a Json Object Hierarchical

 var itemsCount = items.get_count();
            for (var i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                var item = items.itemAt(i);
                var dep = JSON.stringify(item.get_fieldValues());
                deps.push(dep);
            }

           $("#tt").tree({
                data: deps,
                loadFilter: function (data) {
                    return convert(data);
                }
            });
row is valid, but row.DepParentId no

Comment: A jQuery Tree that i'm testing http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tree.php

Comment: i dont see any options being added in the first part. can you make a jsfiddle with some input sample data and expected output? And can you use underscore? it seems you are trying to create a new nested tree with different properties (id,name).

Comment: May be. The full sample is here. http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/tree6.php

Comment: so you want as input  "{"DepId":7,"DepParentId":3,"Title":"OTT"}" and as output "{"Id":7,"parent":3,"name":"OTT"}" you could just use _.map

Comment: ok just check if name and id are in small caps in the sample when they are added and when they are check both are written in small caps id, name (node.id)

Comment: Humm, thanks I'll test. In JsFiddle is ok with the same fields

Comment: yes but since you have different fields i would bet on typo on writing the property, if you share the jsfiddle maybe the community can help you better, abraco

Comment: Hi, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/0drgksmd/3/

Comment: add to that fiddle what you want your output to really look like, and i might be able to help you.

Comment: I think the problem is that i have an [Object<Array>] not a [Object][Object][Object]

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for helping, it's working now, the problem was the JSON.stringify() was returning only an [Object] so when you use JSON.parse() generates a sintax error.

```
 function onLoaded() {

        var itemsCount = items.get_count();
        for (var i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
            var item = items.itemAt(i);
            var dep = JSON.stringify(item.get_fieldValues());
            deps.push(dep);
        }
```

So, i had to change the format to be valid to parse like this

```
        var dt = "[" + deps + "]";
        var ret = JSON.parse(dt);
```

Thanks
Joao